# Creating Rope Physics for Unity

Tags: unity, physics, rope-physics

I want to create a bungee jumping-like game in Unity and therefore I need a rope physics. I especially need elastic ropes with capability to pull objects with velocity after a little extension. Do you know any place to start? Because I have no idea how to start such scripting.

I looked at Asset Store. There are some rope physic simulators, but I have to do it on my own, plus they are really expensive.

**EDIT:** I already tried using Spring and/or Configurable Joints in Unity, but they did not give what I want.

Comment: By now you may have heard of the overused Jakobsen relaxation method, right? You basically have a spring given by its A, B endpoints and you verify how stretched/compressed that spring is w.r.t its restlength. You then directly move A towards B (or away from) with a fraction (typically 0.5) of the displacement from the rest length.. You could also add an elastic force and lower that fraction to 0.2 or 0.05 even to have a stretchier "stiff" spring constraint and.. you're set. Writing a Unity script for that shouldn't be that difficult..

Comment: Actually I have not heard about it, that's why I asked to question, to get a starting point. I am looking for it now. Another point in my mind is that, how to represent this physics with a graphical representation of rope? Should I apply this to a mesh, or create the mesh from some curves or similar to that?

Comment: I googled and found a series of relevant results. These two should help you design simple and efficient constraints, and also integrate/simulate them (if you need to add forces, integrating them is kind of required).. http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/simulate-fabric-and-ragdolls-with-simple-verlet-integration/  and http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~cutler/classes/advancedgraphics/F05/assignments/final_projects/mccarj7/

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped a lot, hopefully I can create the rope I want from these.

Comment: You're welcome; I'm sure you can do it, at least I did it millions of times and so has the community :). Come back if you have any particular issues with it and we'll help you gladly.

Comment: I did that using clothes, result is strange, but it works.

Comment: I think this question is a bit too open-ended. If you could give more details as to what you've tried and *why* it didn't work, that would help a lot for getting you an answer.

Comment: Please reopen this question